# Docker containers not starting automatically after apt upgrade

Tags: docker

After `apt update` and `apt upgrade` all except one docker container aren't started anymore.

Containers have status *exited* using `docker ps -a` and can be started using `docker run $containerid`

Where should I start fixing?

Answer (score 2):

At first you shouldn't use `docker run` for existing containers but `docker start`

From the official documentation :

`docker run`

> Run a command in a new container

`docker start`

> Start one or more stopped *(includes exits)* containers

For your issue, I suggest you to recreate (so with `docker run`) your container with the flag `--restart always` [Source and more info](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)

Comment: I would also mention restarting the docker daemon for containers running in the background e.g., via `-d`.